# Home Interfaces list not populating when importing client jar in EJB transport OSB 12c Jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper, osb, ejb-2.x

Until now whenever client jar is imported in OSB Jdeveloper for EJB transport, list of home and remote interfaces is populated.

> However working with this client jar EJB 2.1, interface list is not
>   populated. I have checked the jar, it is valid and contains
>   interfaces. Also working fine with java code. I am getting:

1. Invalid Ref instance error in JDeveloper
2. In Eclipse OEPE, no error message. Not working here also.

What could be the issue?

[This is how it looks in JDeveloper, getting Invalid Ref instance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsUZv.png)

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be some issue with the EJB Cient jar you are using.

To confirm try with some other client jar, I hope you will not get any issue with that.

Which version of Jdeveloper 12c are you using?

Thanks & Regards,

Tarun

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: "There seems to be some issue with the EJB Cient jar you are using." This is the answer.